# How do i highlight the path of a ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So i have written an R program where i simulate and visualize a sample from the standard coalescent model.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

N <- 10
K <- 20

x <- matrix(0,N,K)
x
for(i in 2:K){
  x[,i] <- sort(sample(N,N,replace = T))
}

f_grid <- expand.grid(x = 1:N, y = 1:K)
df_arrow <- expand.grid(x2 = 1:N, y2 = 2:K, yend = 0, xend = 0)
for(i in 1:nrow(df_arrow)){
  df_arrow[i,]$xend <- x[df_arrow[i,]$x2, df_arrow[i,]$y2]
  df_arrow[i,]$yend <- df_arrow[i,]$y2 - 1
}

ggplot(df_grid, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + 
geom_segment(data = df_arrow, aes(x = x2, y = y2, xend = xend, yend = yend))
```

How can i highlight the path of a random individual from the youngest generation, to the oldest generation. The generation on the top of the plot is the youngest generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another column to your data.frames df_grid and df_arrow and pass that to the colour aesthetic. Then you need to go through your data.frames and identify all the children of your base node in order to change the value of this new column.

Here is a recursive solution but I'm sure it can be improved. Just replace your last two lines with this and change the id parameter to the row number of the individual you want to track.

```
df_arrow$color <- FALSE
df_grid$color <- FALSE
id <- 200
start_point <- df_grid[id,]
ended = FALSE
while(!ended){
  # Find if a segment starts from current point
  slice_iter <- df_arrow$x2 == start_point$x & df_arrow$y2 == start_point$y
  # Update color of current point
  df_grid$color[df_grid$x == start_point$x & df_grid$y == start_point$y] <- TRUE
  if (any(slice_iter)){
    # If there is a segment, update its color
    df_arrow$color[slice_iter] <- TRUE
    # Update the start point to the end point of the segment
    start_point$x <- df_arrow$xend[slice_iter]
    start_point$y <- df_arrow$yend[slice_iter]
  } else ended <- TRUE
  # Do this until there is no segment starting from start_point
}

ggplot(df_grid, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = color)) + 
  geom_point(size = 4) + 
  geom_segment(data = df_arrow, aes(x = x2, y = y2, xend = xend, yend = yend, colour = color), size = 1.1)
```

Take note that this only works if there is only one segment going from young to old, otherwise you'll have to tweak it a bit.

Comment: Thanks you! I will play around with your code :) One more question, if i want to highlight more than one individual, what can i do then?

Comment: Well, it depends if you want them to have different colors or not. If you want them to have different colors, you need different values for color, so replace the TRUE values (except `ended <- TRUE`) with `id`. If not, you don't have to change anything. In both cases, you can run the code from `id <- 200` with a new id each time and redraw the plot for a start but you should actually create a function and iterate on all the individuals you want to track.

Comment: Ok, I will try it out. Thanks for the help :)